# How do theater companies get around discriminatory hiring issues?

Tags: hiring, discrimination

Simply put, when auditioning and consequently hiring actors theater companies do often have to distinguish by race or gender. How do they get around laws prohobiting these sorts of hiring standards?

Comment: It varies from country to country... Not really a workplace question either.

Comment: Why would you hire a 400lb, 60 year old man to play a teenage girl with anorexia?

Comment: The legal term in the US to read up on it would be "bona fide occupational qualifications".

Comment: @JohnHC Why is this not a workplace question?

Comment: @RichardU You wouldn't. But the matter is related if you could turn him down on that basis alone and get away with it. Or rather, how they do.

Comment: Final close vote cast. We tend to frown on trivia questions like this and it's likely too complex of a legal question to be accepted under our "stuff any HR department should know" guideline. And of course you'd need to specify a country before we could even consider whether or not this is really on-topic.

Comment: @WeckarE. This context has nothing to do with racism or discrimination. Since in this context employers are looking for someone who fits a specific character, anyone who doesn't meet those charasteristics is no match. Thus they are not "getting away with it".

Comment: Laws get enforced when someone raises a complaint, goes through an expensive and complex legal obstacle course  and can legitimately provide a compelling case for discrimination, that's never a simple matter. It does happen of course, dance companies have faced challenges for example. Look it up.

Comment: Actually, I saw a play where a middle-aged man in a suit played a teenage girl; and this was fantastic - so, it is possible, but only if the actor is really good :-)

Comment: Although it may not be illegal, there have been many complaints towards Hollywood for casting non-white characters with actors of a different ethnicity or race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since gender, racial, age and body-shape bias is prohibited in general there are several cases that are excluded.

When someone hire people as actors and/or models their body shape, gender, age are mandatory for the decision and there is no objection. The actor is hired because they can act and because they fit in the role description. Actors are rejected because of their hair colour, hair length, teeth, etc. more ridiculous reasons, when compared to "real world" reasons. In case of theatres the ensamble shall cover all role types; when you miss a "princess" type, you need actress that fits in.

For SW developper, for example, there is no need to be woman in 25 years of age with measures 90-60-90; and the law applies there.

Comment: Michael Bay never rejected anyone because of their **teeth** - he replaces teeth not actors.